# GPIO Pins RPi 3 Python

Tags: python, funções, raspberry-pi

estou a começar com um projeto com a minha rpi 3 que conciste em utilizar motores ligados aos pins gpio da rpi3!

No meu codigo tem algum erro ligado a modo dos pins, mas nao sei como resolver, ALGUEM PODERIA DAR UMA AJUDINHA?

```
 import RPi.GPIO as gpio

def up():
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
    gpio.output(7,False)
    gpio.output(11,True)
    gpio.output(13,False)
    gpio.output(15,True)

up()
gpio.cleanup()
```

program output --> 
[image: output]

Comment: Não coloque o erro como imagem, copie e cole aqui no editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa configurar o `GPIO.OUT`. Olha o exemplo abaixo usado para manipular LED.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.LOW)
```